# Why None gets printed at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the main.py file:

```
from data import MENU, resources


def display_resources(store):
    print(f"""Water : {store['water']} ml
Milk  : {store['milk']} ml 
Coffee :{store['coffee']} """)


# TODO 1. Print the resources when user gives input of "report"
user_prompt = input("What would you like to have ? (expresso/latte/cappuccino): ").lower()
if user_prompt == "report":
    print(display_resources(resources))
```

data.py contains

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}
```

When I give "report" as user_prompt, my output loops like:

```
Water :300ml
Milk  :200ml
Coffee :100g
None
```

Why does None get printed at the end of the output?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use two `print` calls. The first in your display function which gives you that you need and the second prints the result of your function but it has no `return` command so returns `None`, change your code to this:

```
from data import MENU, resources

def display_resources(store):
    return f"""Water : {store['water']} ml
Milk  : {store['milk']} ml 
Coffee :{store['coffee']} """


# TODO 1. Print the resources when user gives input of "report"
user_prompt = input("What would you like to have ? (expresso/latte/cappuccino): ").lower()
if user_prompt == "report":
    print(display_resources(resources))
```